# Tkinter grid сетка

Tags: python, tkinter

омогите разобраться с сеткой в tkinter grid. Мне надо чтоб raduibutton были все в один ровный столбец, а получается в разнобой из-за того что в столбце рядом большая кнопка, как сделать так, чтоб сетки друг другу не мешали

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правую часть сделать отдельным фреймом, а в ней все располагать с помощью grid.

Comment: можете пожалуйста привести пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грубый набросок:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Делаем два фрейма рядом друг с другом

left_frame = tk.Frame(root)
left_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
right_frame = tk.Frame(root)
# Т.к. правый фрейм по высоте меньше, то нужно указать, чтобы он заполнил (fill) все пространство
right_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)  

# Заполняем левый фрейм

text = tk.Text(left_frame, width=10, height=10)
text.pack()
button = tk.Button(left_frame, text="text")
button.pack()

# Заполняем правый фрейм

tk.Label(right_frame, text="Right").grid()
tk.Radiobutton(right_frame, text="First").grid(sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(right_frame, text="Second").grid(sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(right_frame, text="Third").grid(sticky=tk.W)
tk.Radiobutton(right_frame, text="Fourth").grid(sticky=tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```

Скриншот:

[image: Скриншот]

Левая и правая сторона окна находятся в разных фреймах, элементы управления у них будут размещаться независимо.